# Can't use jupyter notebook in the global proxy mode of shadowsocks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vpn

I'm a daily user of Jupyter notebook. And I also use shadowsocks for VPN connecting.
However, when I set to the global proxy mode for shadowsocks, I can't open/creat a notebook. However, when I change to the automatic proxy mode, the notebook would run again.

What is the reason for this phenomenon?